# MYOB Import "amount paid"

Tags: import, myob

I seem to have found an anomaly with MYOB (I've actually found many anomalies, this is just another one that is doing my head in...)

I am generating a file with all invoices from the web system - no problems.

If an invoice has 3 lines and the account is paid COD, I am having a problem

e.g.

```
"INV", "DATE" ... "AMOUNT", "INC TAX AMOUNT" ... "AMOUNT PAID"
8421, 12/06/2010 ... 60, 66 ... 66
8421, 12/06/2010 ... 120, 132 ... 132
8421, 12/06/2010 ... 96, 105.6 ... 105.6
8421, 12/06/2010 ... 84, 92.4 ... 92.4
```

When I import this file, the balance of the invoice is still outstanding and what it appears is the issue is that it is only importing the first line of "amount paid", so in other words, based on the above:

1. Invoice 8421 is imported with 4 lines
2. The total invoice amount is $396
3. The Amount paid (that is imported) is $66
4. The outstanding balance = $330

Surely the first line isn't expected to be:

```
Inc tax Amount = $66
Amount Paid = $396
```

It seems completely illogical to me. Am I doing something wrong or is MYOB just really bad?

Answer (score 0):

I did an MYOB export a while back for a while and I do feel your pain :)

I ran into similar issues but I can't remember exactly the problem. There was some issues with line endings though I think (check whether it's \n, \r, \n\r). We also found an issue where we would do the export, the client would open it as a text file (using notepad) and re-save it and somehow that messed up the import.

Text encoding on the export might play some role too. Also make sure that any text is "Quoted" properly.

Not much help sorry, it's been a while

Comment: made my way past all the EOL characters and the many, many problems you come across trying to do a simple import...

Comment: hi, another problem we had - just remembered now - is with account numbers, the account numbers must exist in the MYOB database otherwise it skips the records, no error, no warning, just ignores it..